# Telerik Reporting Pagination Toolbar

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I need to add customize the telerik toolbar or new control to allow pagination in telerik report viewer.Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this:
viewMode: 'PRINT_INTERACTIVE'
to
viewMode: 'PRINT_PREVIEW'